# What is the source of saying pesukei bracha- after motzei shabbos marriv davening?

Tags: havdalah, motzei-shabbos

The Artscroll sidur mentions that these "Verses of Blessing" are a collection of Scriptural passages usually said at home after havdalah.
Where did this originate from?
Is it a minhag?

Comment: Which verses are you talking about? Can you identify an incipit perhaps? Or the page in your Artscoll siddur?

Comment: In the Artscroll Ashkenaz sidur (pg 600), following Vihi Noam and kaddish, it then goes into the verses starting with Viyetan Lecha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom to say the *pesukim* of *Vayitein Lecha* on *Motzei Shabbos* is mentioned by the [*Kol Bo* §41](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%95/%D7%9E%D7%90), and codified in the Rema (295).

> ואומרים ויהי נועם וסדר קדושה באריכות כדי לאחר סדר קדושה שאז חוזרים
> רשעים לגיהנם (טור) ובזמן שאין אומרים ויהי נועם כגון שחל יום טוב בשבוע
> אין אומרים סדר קדושה אבל אומרים ויתן לך (כל בו)

R Yackov Emden (Siddur HaYaavetz) writes:

> אומרים ויתן לך וגו, והם פסוקים של הרבה ברכה והצלחה לסימן טוב בתחילת
> השבוע שיתברכו במעשה ידיהם.‏

Some have the custom to say this during *Maariv*, others have the custom to say it at home before or after *havdallah*.

Comment: [המנהג מוזכר בספרים כל בו ואבודרהם. רבי אברהם בן נתן בספרו 'המנהיג' אומר: "מנהג כל ישראל לומר "ויתן לך", וכל הפסוקים של ברכות, כדי שיתברכו בשבת הבאה (בשבוע הבא), ומעתה ועד עולם".](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%9F_%D7%9C%D7%9A)

Comment: From that link I find this interesting-   וכל הפסוקים של ברכות, כדי שיתברכו בשבת הבאה (בשבוע הבא), ומעתה ועד עולם". 
I am understanding this correctly- the the blessing - that is provided by reciting these pesukim are carried forever?